# Python pandas dataframe print ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,971.25'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python pandas dataframe that should print with the following line:

```
close.loc[stock, str(j)+'_days_ago'] = float(stocks.iloc[[-1 - j]]['Close'].to_string(header=None, index=None))
```

yet I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,971.25'
```

Any ideas how to fix this error?

Comment: It can't convert the value to a string. You can try to remove the comma's, then converting to float will be possible. To do this with your series: `df['column_name'].str.replace(',', '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `,` form the string (provided your decimal separator is the `.`.

I.e. use

```
float('1,971.25'.replace(',', ''))
```

In your code it should be

```
close.loc[stock, str(j)+'_days_ago'] = float(stocks.iloc[[-1 - j]]['Close'].to_string(header=None, index=None).replace(',', ''))
```